# How can I give a specific name to 0th and 1st object of "Items" array of AngularJsonEditor?

Tags: angular, jsoneditor

Example link is here
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rwwjo3?file=src/app/app.component.ts

I want to show a specific name for object 0 and object 1 of Items array. How can I achieve this. I am using NgJsonEditor.

This is HTML code ->
[image: HTML usage screenshot]

This is the .ts ->
[image: .ts file usage screenshot]

And the DATA is ->

export const DATA = {
Items: [{
Name: "A",
NumberProperty: 123,
BooleanProperty: true,
StringProperty: "abc",
OrderBy: "DESC"
}, {
Name: "B",
NumberProperty: 456,
BooleanProperty: false,
StringProperty: "def",
OrderBy: "ASC"
}]
};

[image: result screenshot]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, add a code sample on your question, sometimes links do not work, so code sample is best way to understand your problem and find out a solution. I tried twice but could not reach that web site.

Comment: Added a html and ts screenshot. Thank you @SametÇELİKBIÇAK

Comment: can someone please suggest an answer for the above question..

Comment: When I check the package documentation it use data definition as below,       ```this.data = {"products":[{"name":"car","product":[{"name":"honda","model":[{"id":"civic","name":"civic"},{"id":"accord","name":"accord"},{"id":"crv","name":"crv"},{"id":"pilot","name":"pilot"},{"id":"odyssey","name":"odyssey"}]}]}]}
``` but it your code we could not see your data structure. Could you try example data for your application.  Also you can check this link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-json-editor

Comment: I checked the example link what you have mentioned above, you can see the tree view of json editor, if you expand the products array it's showing the first object as " 0 {2} ", so here instead of "0 {2} " how can I show a specific name.?? @SametÇELİKBIÇAK

Comment: I guess there is no support for it, because of `0{2}` it belongs to array index and values information. I could not find any solution to help.